# Motivic cohomology of $n$-sphere

Tags: motivic-cohomology, motivic-homotopy

All motivic cohomology groups are taken with $\mu_2$ coefficient and $k$ has characteristic different from $2$.

Consider the affine variety $X$ with coordinate ring $k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(x_1^2+\ldots + x_n^2-1)$.

If $k$ contains square root of $-1$ and $n$ is even then this variety may be rewritten as solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^{n/2} x_iy_i-1 $ in affine $n$-space. This is $\mathbb{A}^1$-homotopic to $\mathbb{A}^n\setminus \{0\}$ whose motivic cohomology groups can be computed (at least in terms of the cohomology of the base field) by the Gysin sequence.

If $k$ does not contain square root of $-1$ it seems to me that the motivic cohomology is not known. Could anyone confirm/deny this. If the answer is negative is it possible to compute Chow groups of $X$.

Interestingly the etale cohomology of $X$ can be computed by Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence after adjoinig $\sqrt{-1}$ to $k$ and taking the cover $X_{\sqrt{-1}}\to X$, which is a pullback of $Spec( k(\sqrt{-1}))\to Spec (k)$.

Comment: If $n=2^k$ then the variety is affine Pfister quadric (anisotropic if -1 is not a sum of $2^{k-1}$ squares) whose motive is isomorphic to the Rost motive; in particular, the Chow groups are the same and were computed by Vishik and Yagita. They have 2-torsion, so in general the answer doesn't seem easy.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for computations of Vishik and Yagita?

Comment: See Corollary 6.3 here: https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/plp/pmzav/Papers/visyag3H.pdf
Actually there are some computations of motivic cohomology too.